# Comparing Physical Plans with PushedFilters vs. PartitionFilters in a Spark query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, query-optimization

I have thought of three slightly different ways to query a Spark table to filter the data for a date range (I use it mostly to query one day's worth of data) that I am interested in. When I review the Physical Plans for these three approaches, they are slightly different and I am not sure which one is the best (in terms of being efficient in computation and Spark memory usage). I am hoping that some Spark experts on StackOverflow might be able to advise on

1. which one of them (inner-join-based filter, regular-column-based filter or partition-column based filter) is the best
2. how to benchmark such tests/approaches in Spark (e.g., in Python, I would have use `timeit` and run 100-1000 runs of the same code to measure the time performance. I wonder how to do that with Spark (because each iteration is going to be expensive and long).

I have simplified and added a lot of comments in the code below to explain what I'm trying to test. Thank you in advance for your answers/suggestions!

```
// 'calendar' table used below has just one column 'calendar_day' which has dates spanning from Jan 1, 1970 to Dec 31, 2050
// For fair comparison, we will select only one day from the calendar table like below
val start_day = LocalDate.parse("2023-01-07", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
val end_day = LocalDate.parse("2023-01-07", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
val start_day_literal = lit(Timestamp.valueOf(start_day.atStartOfDay())).cast("timestamp")
val end_day_literal = lit(Timestamp.valueOf(end_day.atStartOfDay())).cast("timestamp")
val t_dates = calendar 
.filter(col("calendar_day") >= start_day_literal)
.filter(col("calendar_day") <= end_day_literal)
.select("calendar_day")
t_dates.show(10, false);
+-------------------+
|calendar_day       |
+-------------------+
|2023-01-07 00:00:00|
+-------------------+

// This is our test#1
// Here, we'll use the broadcast join with t_dates.calendar_day 
// to filter out the rows from the data table.
val test_one = spark
.table("my_data_table")
.withColumn("customer_id", col("beneficiary_external_id").cast("long"))
.withColumn("start_date_trunc", col("start_date").cast("date"))
.withColumn("end_date_nvl", expr("nvl(cast(end_date as date), to_timestamp('2050-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))"))
.join(
    broadcast(t_dates).as("td"),
    joinExprs = col("calendar_day").between(
        lowerBound = col("start_date_trunc"),
        upperBound = col("end_date_nvl")
    ),
    joinType = "inner"
)
.select(
    col("customer_id"),
    col("start_date"),
    col("start_date_trunc"),
    col("start_day"),
    col("end_date"),
    col("end_date_nvl")
)
//test_one.show(100, false)
test_one.explain()
test_one.count(); // 1,999,005,179 rows

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan(isFinalPlan=false)
+- Project [customer_id#163L, start_date#114, start_date_trunc#182, start_day#128, end_date#115, end_date_nvl#202]
   +- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, Inner, ((calendar_day#0 >= cast(start_date_trunc#182 as timestamp)) && (calendar_day#0 <= end_date_nvl#202))
      :- Project [start_date#114, end_date#115, start_day#128, cast(beneficiary_external_id#113 as bigint) AS customer_id#163L, cast(start_date#114 as date) AS start_date_trunc#182, coalesce(cast(cast(end_date#115 as date) as timestamp), 2556057600000000) AS end_date_nvl#202]
      :  +- Filter isnotnull(cast(start_date#114 as date))
      :     +- FileScan parquet my_data_table[beneficiary_external_id#113,start_date#114,end_date#115,start_day#128] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: CatalogFileIndex[s3://aac161b3-4383-880d-29a9-bd3d8e0115d0/9496ff37-0aaf-4b35-a0bc-5363a9213205], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<beneficiary_external_id:string,start_date:timestamp,end_date:timestamp>
      +- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
         +- Filter ((calendar_day#0 >= 1673049600000000) && (calendar_day#0 <= 1673049600000000))
            +- FileScan parquet [calendar_day#0] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://my-bucket/calendar_days/], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [GreaterThanOrEqual(calendar_day,2023-01-07 00:00:00.0), LessThanOrEqual(calendar_day,2023-01-07 ..., ReadSchema: struct<calendar_day:timestamp>
test_one: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [customer_id: bigint, start_date: timestamp ... 4 more fields]
res4: Long = 1999005179



// For test_two, we will create a (mock) timestamp object for Jan 7, 2023, 
// which is the same date that we used for the test_one above.
// This is because we don't want to use inner join with t_dates table.
// Instead, we will replace inner join with filters as shown below.
val dataset_timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2023-01-07 00:00:00.0")

val test_two = spark
.table("my_data_table")
.withColumn("customer_id", col("beneficiary_external_id").cast("long"))
.withColumn("start_date_trunc", col("start_date").cast("date"))
.withColumn("end_date_nvl", expr("nvl(cast(end_date as date), to_timestamp('2050-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))"))
.filter(
    col("start_date_trunc") <= dataset_timestamp
    )
.filter(
    col("end_date_nvl") >= dataset_timestamp
    )
.select(
    col("customer_id"),
    col("start_date"),
    col("start_date_trunc"),
    col("start_day"),
    col("end_date"),
    col("end_date_nvl")
)
//test_two.show(100, false)
test_two.explain()
test_two.count(); // 1,999,005,179 rows; same as test_one

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [cast(beneficiary_external_id#1 as bigint) AS customer_id#51L, start_date#2, cast(start_date#2 as date) AS start_date_trunc#70, start_day#16, end_date#3, coalesce(cast(cast(end_date#3 as date) as timestamp), 2556057600000000) AS end_date_nvl#90]
+- *(1) Filter ((isnotnull(start_date#2) && (cast(cast(start_date#2 as date) as timestamp) <= 1673049600000000)) && (coalesce(cast(cast(end_date#3 as date) as timestamp), 2556057600000000) >= 1673049600000000))
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet my_data_table[beneficiary_external_id#1,start_date#2,end_date#3,start_day#16] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: CatalogFileIndex[s3://aac161b3-4383-880d-29a9-bd3d8e0115d0/9496ff37-0aaf-4b35-a0bc-5363a9213205], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(start_date)], ReadSchema: struct<beneficiary_external_id:string,start_date:timestamp,end_date:timestamp>
dataset_timestamp: java.sql.Timestamp = 2023-01-07 00:00:00.0
test_two: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [customer_id: bigint, start_date: timestamp ... 4 more fields]
res1: Long = 1999005179



// Like test_two, we will create a (mock) timestamp object for Jan 7, 2023 for test_three.
// The  only difference between test_two and test_three is that we are now using start_day', 
// which is a partition column in the data source, in one of the filter statements.
val dataset_timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2023-01-07 00:00:00.0")

val test_three = spark
.table("my_data_table")
.withColumn("customer_id", col("beneficiary_external_id").cast("long"))
.withColumn("start_date_trunc", col("start_date").cast("date"))
.withColumn("end_date_nvl", expr("nvl(cast(end_date as date), to_timestamp('2050-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))"))
.filter(
    col("start_day") <= dataset_timestamp // This is the only difference between test_two and test_three
    )
.filter(
    col("end_date_nvl") >= dataset_timestamp
    )
.select(
    col("customer_id"),
    col("start_date"),
    col("start_date_trunc"),
    col("start_day"),
    col("end_date"),
    col("end_date_nvl")
)
//test_three.show(100, false)
test_three.explain()
test_three.count(); // 1,999,005,179 rows; same as test_one and test_two

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [cast(beneficiary_external_id#130 as bigint) AS customer_id#163L, start_date#131, cast(start_date#131 as date) AS start_date_trunc#182, start_day#145, end_date#132, coalesce(cast(cast(end_date#132 as date) as timestamp), 2556057600000000) AS end_date_nvl#202]
+- *(1) Filter (coalesce(cast(cast(end_date#132 as date) as timestamp), 2556057600000000) >= 1673049600000000)
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet my_data_table[beneficiary_external_id#130,start_date#131,end_date#132,start_day#145] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[s3://aac161b3-4383-880d-29a9-bd3d8e0115d0/9496ff37-0aaf-4b35-a0bc-5363..., PartitionFilters: [(start_day#145 <= 1673049600000000)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<beneficiary_external_id:string,start_date:timestamp,end_date:timestamp>
dataset_timestamp: java.sql.Timestamp = 2023-01-07 00:00:00.0
test_three: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [customer_id: bigint, start_date: timestamp ... 4 more fields]
res2: Long = 1999005179
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best approache is, in order: 3, 2, 1

approache 3: as you can see in the execution plan, your filter is pushed to partition, that mean that the executors won't event load data/file that dont respect the filter. this is a best pratice in Spark. try to filter on partition column as soon as possible.

approache 2: like approche 3 but without partition filter. executors will load data that will be filtered after.

approach 1: it's interesting, no partition filter. you use a `broadcast join` that doesn't provoque `shuffle`, that's a good point. but I dont see how you can beat approach 3 because spark will have to perform a comparaison anyway.

Don't use code based solution to compare time execution. instead, look at spark UI execution time and make sure before comparaison, that your ressource manager (yarn, k8s, ...) give you the same amount of  ressource.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I feel better about approach #3 as well. I will try to deploy these in dev environment and then look at spark UI to make comparisons. I will wait a couple more days before accepting your suggestions above as an answer. Thank you again!